# Adobe Reader renders text spacing incorrectly at different zoom levels

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-reader, rendering

Adobe Reader is shifting certain characters in my PDF left or right, depending on zoom level, when I display it on screen.

When I zoom in, the `M`, `m`, `V`, `v`, `W`, `w`, `Y`, `y`, `1`, and `^` characters move left. When I zoom out, they move right. At 100% zoom they are placed correctly.

Here is a screenshot at 25% zoom:

[image: Screenshot showing how the m character moves to the right when I zoom out.]

Is this a known issue? Can it be fixed with a setting in Adobe Reader, or a change to the PDF?

The text is 16 pt. Consolas, and the font (subset) is embedded in the PDF.

I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 20.006.20034.39303 on Windows 10. My monitor is set to 100% scaling and ClearType is enabled. In Reader `Page Display > Resolution` is set to `Use system setting`, and `Page Display > Rendering > Smooth Text` is set to `For Monitor`.

Comment: Those fonts look rasterized - what zoom level was that image taken at?

Comment: They are not rasterized. The picture is from a zoom level of like 25%, and then I enlarged the image in an image editing program. Sorry, didn't realize that could be misleading.